# Issues Playing A Sound Multiple Times

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

I'm using SpriteKit for my Mac OS project with Objective C and I'm trying to play a certain sound over and over again when contact between two nodes occurs. I don't want the player to wait for the sound to complete before playing it again. The sound is only about 1 second long, but it repeats as fast as every 0.5 seconds. I've tried two different methods and they both have issues. I'm probably not setting something up correctly.

#### Method #1 - SKAction

I tried getting one of the sprites to play the sound using the following code:

```
[playBarNode runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"metronome" waitForCompletion:NO]];
```

The sound plays perfectly on time, but the sound is modified. It sounds like reverb (echo) was applied to it and it has lost a lot of volume as well.

#### Method #2 - AVAudioPlayer

Here's the code I used to set this up:

```
-(void) initAudio {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/metronome.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL *metronomeSound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:metronomeSound error:nil];
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
```

Later on in code it is called like this:

```
[_audioPlayer play];
```

The issue with this one is that it seems to wait until it's completed playing the first time before playing the sound again. Basically it fails to play many times.

Am I setting this up incorrectly? How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Retry method 1, but instead of having the sprite play the sound, have the scene play the sound via

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"metronome" waitForCompletion:NO]];
```

inside the game SKScene class

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it's exactly the same result.

Comment: Interesting, I hope you figure it out. I've used this exact method in my games and it works perfectly. Have you maybe tried it with another random sound file to see if the same problem happens to make sure it's not that one particular file? Also maybe try changing the file type to .WAV or some other extension.

Comment: I have a feeling it's because the sound is very short. Like you, I've never had problems like this before and I've been using SpriteKit for a while. The issue with things this time is that I need the sound to be perfectly on time since this is a rhythm app and it's for the metronome sound.Another issue with using the SpriteKit method is that you have no control over volume, which I think could be important for a sound like this.I just tried to load and play the sound asynchronously and it worked very well, but I know very little about using background threads and I hope memory is not affected.

Comment: that should work, as long as you don't have more than maybe 10 of them playing at a time (which seems unlikely)